# List of service workers in Qt WebEngine

Tags: qt, chromium, qtwebengine

I'm using Qt WebEngine (chromium).
The question is, can I get a list of all service workers and their statuses using Qt or something else. And handle this info in code

I would like to get information from the Application developer console, like on the screenshot [service workers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Trt.png)

Solutions I tried:

1. It is not possible to obtain a list of workers through a java script, plus this solution is not technically suitable
2. Use QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor, and try to intercept request with type QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo::ResourceTypeServiceWorker. It didn't work.